# Finish VS Complete in this context

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I heard people say:

> A: Hurry up!
>
> B: Hang on! Let me **complete** my work.

But many people in this context use:

> Hang on! Let me **finish** my work.

Are they interchangeable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "complete" and "finish" mean the same thing. You can use these words interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference between 'complete' and 'finish' in the following sentences:

*"Hang on! Let me complete my work."*
&
*"Hang on! Let me finish my work."*

But sometimes the verb 'finish' has a negative connotation : the sentence "She finished my life" means 'she ruined my life'. In this context, the verb 'complete' cannot be used.

Similarly, the verb 'complete' has a positive connotation : the sentence "You have completed my life" may be a  husband's Good Night message for his wife, meaning "without you, my life is incomplete".

Now, let me quote a WhatsApp message in this context :

"When you marry a right woman you are complete. When you marry a wrong woman you are finished. When the right woman sees you with a wrong woman, you are completely finished."